# How to send a realtime count of active WebSocket connections over an Akka HTTP WebSocket? (works with just Akka Streams)

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

How can a realtime count of active WebSocket connections be sent over an Akka WebSocket? It seems Akka HTTP WebSockets change the running of Akka Stream's prepend stage.

In the first code block below, the count is only sent immediately when it is the only connection. Any clients which connect when there is already a count more than 1 do not receive an update until the **next** client connects.

The second code block has the WebSocket code removed so that only Akka Streams are used, and every stream subscription **does** receive an immediate count as shown on stdout.

### Using Akka HTTP WebSocket

Running this code and accessing http://localhost:8080 with multiple browser windows shows this in their browser consoles.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{BroadcastHub, Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor

object CounterFlow {

    private implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("CounterFlowTest")
    private implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    private implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = actorSystem.dispatcher

    val (counterSourceQueue, counterSource) =
        Source.queue[Int](0, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
            .conflate(_ + _)
            .scan(0)(_ + _)
            .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 1))(Keep.both)
            .run()

    val clientFlow: Source[TextMessage.Strict, Unit] =
        counterSource
            .map(_.toString)
            .map(TextMessage.Strict)
            .prepend(Source.fromIterator(() => {
                counterSourceQueue.offer(1)
                Iterator.empty
            }))
            .watchTermination()((_, done) => done.foreach(_ => counterSourceQueue.offer(-1)))

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val route: Route =
            pathEndOrSingleSlash {
                get {
                    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
                        "<h1>Check browser console for connection count</h1>" +
                            "<script>const ws = new WebSocket(\"ws://localhost:8080/ws\");ws.onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);</script>"))
                }
            } ~
                path("ws") {
                    handleWebSocketMessages(
                        Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(
                            Sink.ignore,
                            clientFlow))
                }

        Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
        () // discard non-Unit value
    }
}
```

### Akka Streams Only

As seen on stdout, each client receives an immediate count as desired.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{BroadcastHub, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object CounterFlow {

    private implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("CounterFlowTEst")
    private implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val (counterSourceQueue, counterSource) = Source.queue[Int](0, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
        .conflate(_ + _)
        .scan(0)(_ + _)
        .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink)(Keep.both)
        .run()

    def subscribeClient(clientName: String): Unit =
        counterSource
            .prepend(Source.fromIterator(() => {
                counterSourceQueue.offer(1)
                Iterator.empty
            }))
            .watchTermination()((_, done) => done.foreach(_ => counterSourceQueue.offer(-1)))
            .runWith(Sink.foreach(msg => println(s"$clientName $msg")))
            .foreach(_ => println(s"$clientName Done"))

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        subscribeClient("A")
        subscribeClient("B")
        Thread.sleep(500L)
        subscribeClient("C")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing `BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 1)` to `BroadcastHub.sink` (as it is in the Akka Streams version) each client receives the count immediately.

Here's the version I tested with:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{BroadcastHub, Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor

object CounterFlow {

    private implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("CounterFlowTest")
    private implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    private implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = actorSystem.dispatcher

    val (counterSourceQueue, counterSource) =
        Source.queue[Int](0, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
            .conflate(_ + _)
            .scan(0)(_ + _)
            .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink)(Keep.both)
            .run()

    val clientFlow: Source[TextMessage.Strict, Unit] =
        counterSource
            .map(_.toString)
            .map(TextMessage.Strict)
            .prepend(Source.fromIterator(() => {
                counterSourceQueue.offer(1)
                Iterator.empty
            }))
            .watchTermination()((_, done) => done.foreach(_ => counterSourceQueue.offer(-1)))

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val route: Route =
            pathEndOrSingleSlash {
                get {
                    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
                        "<p>Connections: <span id='c'>?</span></p>" +
                            "<script>const ws = new WebSocket(\"ws://localhost:8080/ws\");ws.onmessage = e => { console.log(e.data); document.getElementById('c').innerText = e.data; };</script>"))
                }
            } ~
                path("ws") {
                    handleWebSocketMessages(
                        Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(
                            Sink.ignore,
                            clientFlow))
                }

        Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
        () // discard non-Unit value
    }
}
```

PS: very nice example!

Comment: That causes a default buffer size of 256 to be used for the BroadcastHub - is this just covering up the underlying race condition?

Comment: Yes, probably. I didn't follow the discussion you had with Johannes about there potentially being a race condition.